# Get URL to MSM sites

Tags: multi-site-manager

How do you link one MSM site to another? Or putting another way, how can I get the site_url config item for a specific subsite (without resorting to PHP)?
Seems like a very basic question, but couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some example code for what you are attempting?
I tested {site_name:site_url} and that doesn't work.
You could create snippets in the default_site and make them available globally that contain the site url for each site. Then you could use {site_default_url} etc. Or what ever naming convention you choose.

Comment: Snippets could be a solution, but then it would be necessary to change them when going into production. Not a big deal, but something as simple as {subsite_url} or {path="group/template" site="subsite"} would be very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this deficiency too - In the end I created each subsite's URL as a global variable for cross-site usage. ([FocusLab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) helps with that).

Comment: That's helpful! From config.php I can also set them according to the current environment.